# .htaccess not working in files folder to disable php files from executing in files folder

Tags: 7, .htaccess

I have the following in my default/files/.htaccess file:

```
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006                                                                                                                                                                                    
Options None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

But I am still able to execute php files in my files folder. What is wrong with my .htaccess file or how do I even verify if my .htaccess file is even working.

Comment: Here’s a post describing how to test if htaccess is working, https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2007-11-24/testing-if-htaccess-is-working

Comment: Might you be running on [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/), which doesn't use .htaccess?
Either way, htaccess is not where you want to be disabling scripts. See [this](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2009-12-05/what-on-earth-is-this-sethandler-drupal_security_do_not) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct .htaccess file in another drupal install. The file should contain:

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Options None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Options +FollowSymLinks                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.                                                                                                                                                                          
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006                                                                                                                                                                                     
<Files *>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

# Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.                                                                                                                                                                      
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003                                                                                                                                                                                   
</Files>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.                                                                                                                                                                           
<IfModule mod_php5.c>                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
php_flag engine off                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
</IfModule>
```

php files wont work now in the files folder.